# Fatal error: Class 'plgContentWidgetkit_Content' not found in

Tags: joomla, joomla-widgetkit

My website http://gutenberginstitute.com was developped using joomla and yootheme "venice". However, I have download and installed Widgetkit (free version so far) to test it on my site, and I can't make it work. It seems there are some plugins that are not installed, and if I put
...
[widgetkit id=1]
...
in some article, for example...

http://gutenberginstitute.com/index.php/es/our-teachers-es

It's not converted into the widget, but it shows just "[widgetkit id=1]"

On the other hand, if I use the module that gets created after the installation of widgetkit, in the "Modules" tab, I get an error when trying to show the article:

> Fatal error: Class 'plgContentWidgetkit_Content' not found in
> {..}public_html/administrator/components/com_widgetkit/helpers/system.php
> on line 312

Anyone know what could be here happening?

Comment: Try uninstalling widgetkit, and then installing it again. one done, ensure everything was installed correctly. You should also make sure the wdigetkit plugin is enabled

Comment: All plugins are enabled. I have unistalled it about 10 times. Even installing other versions doesn't fix the problem, widgetkit behaviour is quite weird :( But I don't get any javascript error in the cosole, nothing :(

Comment: Now, with the new widgetkit, ZOO and K2 installed - the same. 1) either it shows "[widgetkit id=1]"  in text or, if creating a module, it just displays the title but not the widget, as shown in http://gutenberginstitute.com/index.php/our-teachers.  It seems to be a conflict somewhere, but I don't know where to start from.

Answer (score 0):

This is already fixed. It was related to different uikit.js version (2.18) and templates (2.20) and yoo_theme out of date. Update your yoo_theme version and all the rest will be fixed automatically!